# How can I make my D-Bus service exit automatically when idle?

Tags: python, service, systemd, dbus, gdbus

I have a D-Bus service written in Python with GDBus (using bindings provided by [PyGObject](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/pygobject/)).

Since it's written in Python and has a few dependencies, that service has a relatively big memory footprint (about 30MiB). It's only needed when the client app is actually being used by the user, so most of the time it's just sitting around idle. It's installed as a D-Bus-activated systemd service, so it's started on-demand.

I'm looking for a way to have it automatically exit if it hasn't been used for some time. I was hoping that systemd could do this for me automatically but it doesn't seem to support that. It [does implement this feature](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/b5a3418332bbac3e499b98645f4cc3d586516fd6/src/shared/bus-util.c#L97-L148) for its own services though. I also found [this PoC](https://github.com/cgwalters/test-exit-on-idle) for a race-free exit-on-idle GDBus service but it's written in C.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing [my own Python module](https://github.com/adombeck/python-gdbus-util) which implements race-free exit-on-idle, inspired by [the systemd code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/b5a3418332bbac3e499b98645f4cc3d586516fd6/src/shared/bus-util.c#L97-L148) and the [PoC by cgwalters](https://github.com/cgwalters/test-exit-on-idle).

It's available as a [PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/gdbus-util), so you can install it via pip:

```bash
pip install gdbus-util
```

It's documented on https://python-gdbus-util.readthedocs.io.

Example usages can be found [here](https://github.com/adombeck/python-gdbus-util/tree/main/examples).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to advertise your package.

Comment: The code to do a race-free exit on idle already exists in https://gitlab.gnome.org/pwithnall/libgsystemservice/-/blob/main/libgsystemservice/service.c?ref_type=heads

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Interesting! I explicitly searched for something like that on gitlab.gnome.org before I started implementing it myself. I might have worked on Python bindings for that instead if I had found it.